# Blocking disabled users firebase rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am not sure whether this will work but I was wondering if it is possible to block storage/firestore reads/writes in the rules if a user has been disabled. Is this possible e.g. context.auth.disabled?

Or do i just have to wait for the token to expire for users to be denied access

Answer (score 4):

Disabling a user means that they can't sign in anymore, nor refresh their ID token. In practice this means that within an hour of disabling the user they can no longer have a `request.auth.uid` in your security rules.

But as long as their existing ID token is valid, there's nothing you can do to invalidate that individual token. If you want to prevent them from accessing the data immediately, you'd have to create a list of blocked UIDs in your database, and check that in your security rules.

For an example of this, see the Firebase documentation on [detecting ID token revocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation). The example uses Realtime Database, but the same approach would work for Firestore.